# error: ‘HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING’ is not a member of ‘cv’

Tags: c++, opencv

I am upgrading an existing code base that use OpenCV 2 and 3 to be compatible with my Ubuntu 20.04 that uses OpenCV 4. One error I encountered when compiling is:

**error: ‘HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING’ is not a member of ‘cv’; did you mean ‘CASCADE_DO_CANNY_PRUNING’?**

Should I accept the change proposed by the compiler and change `cv::HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING` to `cv::CASCADE_DO_CANNY_PRUNING` for all occurrences?

Comment: looks good to me.

Comment: Yeah, the values of the 4 `CASCADE_*` symbols match the ones of the old  `HAAR_*` symbols.

Comment: I replaced and it seems to be good. Thanks! I couldn't find related info on the internet therefore I asked. Hopefully helps the next person.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I accept the change proposed by the compiler?

Yes.

The values of the 4 `CASCADE_*` symbols match the ones of the old `HAAR_*` symbols, as @DanMasek commented.

You can check the enums in [Enumeration Type Documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/d54/group__objdetect.html#ggae4c91f4a5c56d2d3e71f77a08434e75ba04a050084d81a4a05abe92b7fc9ef210) and [OpenCV-2_2 Reference](https://mesonpi.cat.cbpf.br/_coteccomp/downloads/opencv-2_2_manref.pdf), page 795.